# cob_camera_sensors launch file missing

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am buildind the system under indigo and check out the indigo branch. However their are no launch files for the running "roslaunch cob_camera_sensors" only a python script file exists.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223969/cob_camera_sensors-launch-file-missing/) by [mpatalberta](https://answers.ros.org/users/23552/mpatalberta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package cob_camera_sensors is deprecated and only kept for backwards compatibility. There are a lot of other  packages that provide the same driver functionality but in a more genericc implementation.

see http://wiki.ros.org/camera_drivers

---

Originally posted by [FlorianWeisshardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25562/florianweisshardt/) with karma: 41 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0